# Cannot change php from localhost details to my servers to connect sql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to php/sql and i have a login system which runs on my local host using xammp and it all works fine. I now want to upload it to my website but the code no longer works... I have created a sql db on my hosting service and tried to change the code.

the code that is used on the local host is

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

and this is the code that i have got from my hosting.

```
<?php
$host_name = 'db682827654.db.1and1.com';
$database = 'db682827654';
$user_name = 'dbo682827654';
$password = '<Enter your password here.>';

$conn = mysql_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysql_errno()) {
die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysql_error().'</p>');
} else {
echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.</p >';
}
?>
```

however this brings up an errror message. I have changed the password to the password for my database but its still not connecting.

This is the error message.

```
   Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'dbo706265806'@'217.160.62.78' (using password: YES)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try local address 127.0.0.1.  Seen this happen before where localhost doesn't resolve for "security reasons".

Comment: Also helpful to post the specific error you're getting, cause otherwise we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli_connect` (not `mysql_connect`) like localhost:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "db682827654.db.1and1.com";
$dbUsername = "dbo682827654";
$dbPassword = "<Enter your password here.=)>";
$dbName = "db682827654";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for that. I have followed what you said and now i am getting this error message. 

Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'dbo706265806'@'217.160.62.78' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

On your computer you are using `mysqli_connect`, but on the server you are trying to use `mysql_connect`. Just use the same file from your computer and simply change `$dbServername`, `$dbUsername`, `$dbPassword` and `$dbName` to match those that your hosting provided.